# Algorithm addgeometryattributes not found

Tags: qgis, geometry, qgis-3, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I am trying to find area and perimeters of Polygon using Pyqgis3. I tried manually first `Vector`->`Geometry Tools`->`Add Geometry Attributes`. By doing so, I get  the area and perimeter column in the attribute table. I would like to automate this process by using python -console inside qgis. I tried the following code, but i get " Algorithm  addgeometryattributes" not found.

```
Inputparameters={'INPUT':'C:/Demand/war.shp','CALC_METHOD':0,'OUTPUT':'C:/Demand/wardge.csv'}


processing.run('qgis:addgeometryattributes',Inputparameters)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm id has different name in QGIS 3. It is `qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns` as you can see below:

[image]

Try to use the above id name, and check if it works.

Comment: Hi does this give a correct area in metre^2 if the coordinate system of my shape file is WGS 84 / UTM zone 43N ESPG:32643 ?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, but the unit of WGS 84 / UTM zone 43N EPSG:32643 is in meter, and thus, the area will be in meter square. https://epsg.io/32643. Anyway if you have a new question, please ask in a new thread.